# Visitor Pattern implementation in Python

Tags: python, python-decorators, visitor-pattern

I am doing some research on the Visitor Design Pattern implementations in Python and came across an interesting version which I see a lot of potential to use in real world scenarios but it also confuse me as well.

I extracted the code below from this [url](https://tavianator.com/2014/python_visitor.html):

```
# A couple helper functions first

def _qualname(obj):
    """Get the fully-qualified name of an object (including module)."""
    return obj.__module__ + '.' + obj.__qualname__

def _declaring_class(obj):
    """Get the name of the class that declared an object."""
    name = _qualname(obj)
    return name[:name.rfind('.')]

# Stores the actual visitor methods
_methods = {}

# Delegating visitor implementation
def _visitor_impl(self, arg):
    """Actual visitor method implementation."""
    method = _methods[(_qualname(type(self)), type(arg))]
    return method(self, arg)

# The actual @visitor decorator
def visitor(arg_type):
    """Decorator that creates a visitor method."""

    def decorator(fn):
        declaring_class = _declaring_class(fn)
        _methods[(declaring_class, arg_type)] = fn

        # Replace all decorated methods with _visitor_impl
        return _visitor_impl

    return decorator

class Lion: pass
class Tiger: pass
class Bear: pass

class ZooVisitor:
    @visitor(Lion)
    def visit(self, animal):
        return "Lions"

    @visitor(Tiger)
    def visit(self, animal):
        return "tigers"

    @visitor(Bear)
    def visit(self, animal):
        return "and bears, oh my!"

animals = [Lion(), Tiger(), Bear()]
visitor = ZooVisitor()
print(', '.join(visitor.visit(animal) for animal in animals))
# Prints "Lions, tigers, and bears, oh my!"
```

The part which causes the confusion is `print(', '.join(visitor.visit(animal) for animal in animals))` - I am aware that it would print the result dynamically based on the class assigned in the decorator but I do not grasp the idea how it works under the hood.
What I tried is to debug it in the IDE and found out that after the line `print(', '.join(visitor.visit(animal) for animal in animals))` the `decorator(fn)` inner function did not execute as I go through the debug process instead it jumped to `_visitor_impl(self, arg)` function but the `decorator(fn)` actually got executed and the debugger does not show it as I tried to comment out the part below in the mentioned function:

```
declaring_class = _declaring_class(fn)
_methods[(declaring_class, arg_type)] = fn
```

and got the following error:

```
"D:\Program Files\Python\python.exe" "E:/Udemy/Design Patterns/Python_test/test.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Udemy/Design Patterns/Python_test/test.py", line 53, in <module>
    print(', '.join(visitor.visit(animal) for animal in animals))
  File "E:/Udemy/Design Patterns/Python_test/test.py", line 53, in <genexpr>
    print(', '.join(visitor.visit(animal) for animal in animals))
  File "E:/Udemy/Design Patterns/Python_test/test.py", line 18, in _visitor_impl
    method = _methods[(_qualname(type(self)), type(arg))]
KeyError: ('__main__.ZooVisitor', <class '__main__.Lion'>)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Also, I replicated the decorating behavior as below:

```
def decorator_function(original_function):
    def wrapper_function(test):
        print(test)
        return original_function()
    return wrapper_function


@decorator_function
def display():
    print('display function ran')

display('test2')
```

In the scipt above, the debugger did go into the `wrapper_function()` and executed all the step in there unlike the Visitor Design Pattern which jumped straight to `_visitor_impl(self, arg)`

My question is:
Why does the Visitor Design Pattern script does not go into its wrapper function `decorator(fn)` ?

As the debugger does not show how the `visitor()` function process, how does the `visitor(arg_type)`, `_visitor_impl(self, arg)`, `_qualname(obj)` &  `_declaring_class(obj)` interact with each others ?

Comment: One thing to note is that `visitor()` and `decorator()` are only executed as the `ZooVisitor` class is defined and never at 'runtime'.

Comment: @quamrana, Do you mean that `visitor()` and `decorator()` run at line `visitor = ZooVisitor()` as I debugged on this line as well but it did not jump to these functions or maybe can you elaborate further ?

Comment: No. Classes in python are 'executed' as python reads the code. One part of this is that it calls any decorators whilst defining methods of a class. I think of this like python is executing: `ZooVisitor.visit = visitor(Lion)(visit)`, which is very similar to: `ZooVisitor.visit = decorator(visit)`. You should try to set a break point inside `def visitor()`.

Comment: Thank you @quamrana for pointing me to the right direction of debugging. Actually, those mentioned methods which caused me the confusion were executed when the classes were defined and I looked into the wrong place.